# How to prove $P(a \geq b +c) \leq P(a \geq b) + P(c \leq 0)?$

Tags: machine-learning, probability, mathematical-statistics

How to prove $$P(a\geq b+c)\leq P(a\geq b)+P(c\leq0)?$$

Thanks.

Comment: $a\ge b+c$ happens when either (i) $a\ge b+c$ _and_ $c\ge 0$ or (ii) $a\ge b+c$ _and_ $c\le 0$, which are incompatible events.

Answer (score 0):

The critical relation is:
$$P(a\geq b+c)\leq P(a\geq b \cup c \leq 0)$$
because RHS is more general, i.e. when it doesn't happen, we have $a<b\cap c>0$, in which we cannot have $a\geq b+c$.

Then, we just apply set rules:
$$P(a\geq b+c)\leq P(a\geq b)+P(c\leq 0)-P(a\leq b\cap c\leq 0)\leq P(a\geq b)+P(c\leq 0)$$